# Counter resets every time my while loops?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a script to restart a process if the associated screen isn't found after 5 checks:

```
f=0
while true; do(
    for s in server1 server2 server3; do(
            if ! screen -ls|grep -q "$s"; then(
                    f=$(($f + 1))
                    #Here, f is always 1 more than the value
                    #I set at the beginning of the script
                    echo "$s missed $f heartbeats"
            )else(
                    f=0
            )fi

            if [ "$f" -ge 5 ]; then(
                    echo "`date`: $s down, starting"
                    /path/to/start/script
            )fi
    )done
sleep 1
#f is 0 here
)done
```

`f` is being set back to the initial value after each iteration of the while loop, even though I don't set `f` within the loop. How can I make my counter persist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unnecessary parentheses you use to enclose the bodies of each loop and `if` statement form a subshell, and any changes made to a variable in a subshell are local to that shell and vanish when the subshell exits.

```
f=0
while true; do
    for s in server1 server2 server3; do
        if ! screen -ls|grep -q "$s"; then
            f=$(($f + 1))
            echo "$s missed $f heartbeats"
        else
            f=0
        fi
        if [ "$f" -ge 5 ]; then
            echo "`date`: $s down, starting"
            /path/to/start/script
        fi
    done
    sleep 1
done
```

From the SHELL GRAMMAR section of the `bash` man page (emphasis mine):

> (list) list  is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  **Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command
>                 completes.**  The return status is the exit status of list.